# How To Mark An Item From A Queue List [Python]

Tags: python, queue

I have a list of strings in Queue

```
queue = ["First","Second","Third","Fourth","",etc]
```

Snippet Of The Code :

```
import thread
from thread import Threading
import Queue
import time

class MainThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        Details = self.queue.get()
        Trail = Details
        #..........#
        # Now Mark If Trail Can Be Use Again Or Not
        self.queue.put(Trail) # Now Put Them Back No Matter What
        self.queue.task_done()

queue = Queue.Queue(maxsize=0)
while not #...........#
    for i in range(TotalThreads):
        try:
            t = ThreadingPower(queue)
            t.setDaemon(False)
            t.start()
        except:
            time.sleep(5)
```

My question : if the string "First" from queue can't be used again,how can i mark it for a specific time,so the thread can continue grabbing other and ignore it until the specific time is over

Edit :

Currently the solution i have is

```
queue = [["First",1],["Second",1],["Third",1],["Fourth",1],etc]


class MainThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
    def run(self):
    Details = self.queue.get()
    Trail,State = Details
    if State == 1:
        #................#
        if #.............#:
            State = 0
    self.queue.put((Trail,State)) # Now Put Them Back No Matter What
    self.queue.task_done()

queue = Queue.Queue(maxsize=0)
while not #...........#
    for i in range(TotalThreads):
        try:
            t = ThreadingPower(queue)
            t.setDaemon(False)
            t.start()
        except:
            time.sleep(5)
```

However this only works if i want to disable them permanently,i need a solution where i can disable them for a specific time

Comment: What determines if a string can be used again?

Comment: its between 5-15 seconds after disabled sometimes 45 seconds - 5 minutes

Comment: Why don't you just put the "string task" on a different thread, and go on poping element from queue?

Comment: still need help

Comment: On what matter? have you tried my advice?

Comment: i don't understand what your advice meant,however i tried adding Boolean datatag,however it only works if i want to disable them permanently